# How do I make a page stick to screen when scrolling in and out?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

<strike>The title sounds really stupid, and its hard to explain with such small characters, so here we go.
I want the whole website to resize its self once the user zooms out or just has a smaller screen resolution. Its hard to explain, but you can check an example at: https://panicatthedisco.com.</strike>

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I would like the website to stick to the same zoom no matter what the user does to their zoom or resolution. So, if the user zooms to 140, it'll still display as 100.

Comment: Are you talking about the way the background image always fills the window?

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you're asking. That site does a number of different things when you resize the window, it's hard to tell what you're asking about.

Comment: @Barmar Scrap that, I'd like the website to stay the exact some resolution and zoom no matter what the 'viewer' changes it to.

Comment: I just tried using zoom, it seems like an incredibly bad idea to override that.

Comment: @Barmar whys that

Comment: People zoom in for a reason, usually because they can't read the text. putting everything back to the same resolution will prevent this.

Comment: My font size is fairly big, so they don't need to worry.
Could you possibly help?

Comment: You could also start by reading the Javascript for that site and looking for the code that runs on the `resize` event.

Comment: are you asking a way to control the 'zoom levels' of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to scale your site to the device width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Edit: Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Doesn't help with the question I asked.

Comment: Unless you clarify the question, you're going to get lots of inappropriate answers.

Comment: @Barmar check comments on your post.

Comment: That code will cause most elements on your site to resize based on screen size or zoom (phones, TV's, etc.) That code is implemented on the page you linked as an example. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: I have this meta on my website www.bridgebase.com, it doesn't override the zoom mechanism like that example site does.

Answer (score 0):

Set the html font size to something like 16px for desktop, then in your media queries change the font size to smaller sizes, like 15px, 14px, etc.  This only works if all of your units are in rem, so you will need to change them.

Comment: I'm not sure he's talking about font sizes.